# Is there any shortcut for custom attributes using IntelliSense Emmet?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

For example, i want to enter with this input:

```
.classOne#idOne?customAttribute?customAttributeValue
```

And then, when hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> on keyboard I want get this output:

```
<div class="classOne" id="idOne" customAttribute="customAttributeValue"></div>
```

What are the {`?`} characters to make this input/output possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Emmet Docs](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) can describe how to do it.

Input:

```
.classOne#idOne[customAttribute=customAttributeOne]
```

Output:

```
<div class="classOne" id="idOne" customAttribute="customAttributeOne"></div>
```

Comment: You can cite people, but if you're citing then you should include the relevant parts in quotes (prefixing lines in your answer with > formats them as quotes) and provide a link directly to the source, not just to their website

Answer (score -1):

You can put custom snippets in snippets.json

https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/emmet/#using-custom-emmet-snippets